# Visual Studio .NET (ordering classes and forms)

Tags: .net, user-interface, visual-studio-2013

Using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, is it possible to change the display order of my forms/classes within my solution explorer?

Consider the below screenshot.

[image: Example #1]

Let's say I wanted to configure that window so the forms/classes read in this order.

1. **MMC**

   - initial.vb

     - systemchecks.vb
   - main.vb

     - loadevents.vb
     - messages.vb

I apologise if this is a simple question, but simply dragging and dropping does not work and I can't see options to change display/sub-display orders. - Google wasn't helpful either, but I can't be the only one who has wanted to keep everything organised.

Research determines that it's done alphabetically, is there hack or anything available? - I would of thought that the most recent release would have such a feature?

Comment: No such feature exist.  Can't change the sort order, can't nest them, you get the same order you'd get when you use Explorer.  Adding such a feature it is pretty much guaranteed to make nobody happy, everybody wants their own.  Use [user voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio) to ask for features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature. The file order is fixed. You can however use folders to sort your files. You could have a folder named "Forms" and one named "Logics" or if you prefer to keep the logic and presentation close together, you can have a folder "Login" and the login form and logic and database access classes all in this folder.

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat of a hack, but you can do this by manually editing your `csproj` file and adding a `<DependentUpon>` xml element. For example

```
<Compile Include="loadevents.vb">
  <DependentUpon>main.vb</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Code</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="messages.vb">
  <DependentUpon>main.vb</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Code</SubType>
</Compile>
```

This is in fact the way Visual Studio groups other file types, like a form with its designer and its code behind.

Comment: Thank you for the hack, however I think the folder way below is sufficient enough for me.